# Regex capture groups for csv with single quoted columns with escaped single quotes inside?

Tags: regex

I have a csv that has some columns quoted with single quotes. Inside one of these columns I have escaped single quotes that I want to be part of the capture group.

Here is as far as I have got with my regex:

```regex
(?<time>[^,]*),([^,]*),(?<user>[^,]*),(?<ip>[^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),(?<type>[^,]*),(?<database>[^,]*),'(?<query>[^',]*)
```

Here is a line from my log:

```
20220413 10:21:51,4c5c64e0ea2a,root,172.18.0.3,253985,19577453,QUERY,MyDatabase,'INSERT INTO MyDatabase.`ICProcessStatus` (`ICID`, `Status`, `AgencyUser`, `VBReason`, `DOLCReason`, `Ordinal`, `Date_Modified`)\n                \tVALUES ( NAME_CONST(\'_ICID\',11111),  NAME_CONST(\'_Status\',31),  NAME_CONST(\'_User\',NULL),  NAME_CONST(\'_VBReason\',NULL),  NAME_CONST(\'_DOLCReason\',NULL), 0,  NAME_CONST(\'_Date_Modified\',TIMESTAMP\'2022-04-13 10:21:51\'))',0
```

The query capture group should contain:

```
INSERT INTO MyDatabase.`ICProcessStatus` (`ICID`, `Status`, `AgencyUser`, `VBReason`, `DOLCReason`, `Ordinal`, `Date_Modified`)\n                \tVALUES ( NAME_CONST(\'_ICID\',11111),  NAME_CONST(\'_Status\',31),  NAME_CONST(\'_User\',NULL),  NAME_CONST(\'_VBReason\',NULL),  NAME_CONST(\'_DOLCReason\',NULL), 0,  NAME_CONST(\'_Date_Modified\',TIMESTAMP\'2022-04-13 10:21:51\'))
```

Comment: This seems to work ```(?<time>[^,]*),([^,]*),(?<user>[^,]*),(?<ip>[^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),(?<type>[^,]*),(?<database>[^,]*),'(?<query>[^\b]*)',(?<error>[^,]*)``` but using a word boundary might not be the best idea?